# Bootstrap hamburger button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, hamburger-menu

I've been trying to fix my menu for a while with no luck:

My menu:

```
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
            <ul class="primary-nav">
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="root.anchor({scrollTo: 'service'})">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="root.anchor({scrollTo: 'downloads-info'})">Downloads</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="root.anchor({scrollTo: 'partners'})">Partners</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a ui-sref="root.anchor({scrollTo: 'contact'})">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="#" class="nav-toggle">Menu<span></span></a>
```

I'm loading bootstrap & jquery:

```
<script src="Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

However, I'm seeing two very weird things: on my localhost, when i downsize my browser, the menu flashes at me and disappears, no console errors are thrown, but up on my dev server, I get the hamburger button, but it does nothing when clicked.  I'm not very sure where to look for the issue as I'm not seeing any errors.  I'm running ui-router, not sure how much it likes the href="#", html5mode set to false. There's also a bunch of css from a template behind the classes as well as a javascript function for opening the menu that doesn't seem to be firing either.  Any help would be appreciated!